# Does Google-cloud-PubSub support amqp 1.0 protocol?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amqp, google-cloud-pubsub

I couldn't really find any references pertaining to the above question. Has anyone tried to use amqp 1.0 with Google cloud's [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)? Is it even supported or is it supposed to be used as a standalone vendor offering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not seeing any immediate reference to direct AMQP support but maybe a transform package might help.  For example Apache Beam (GCP DataFlow) can read/write AMQP and GCP Pub/Sub.  Also Apache NiFi also has AMQP and GCP Pub/Sub.  It wouldn't be too hard to front end Pub/Sub with an AMQP proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pubsub is not compliant with AMQP. You have product with similar propocol, like [MQTT for IoT core product](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge), but when a message is in PubSub, only HTTP and gRPC communication are supported.